# Google Cloud SQL get overview I/O

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have two questions:
1) Is there any possibility to find out the total number of I/Os for the ongoing month? (or for other periods)
2) Is it possible to find out the number of I/O's for a SQL Statement? (I know, that this depends on the usage of Memcache, but I would like to know, if a optimized statement generates less I/O's compared to the initial one without regarding Memchache).

Answer (score 0):

You can see all "unbilled usage" for your project at https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/billing/unbilledinvoice. This is an estimate that is updated daily. The "Google SQL Service Read and write count" row is probably the one you want.

You might also like to check out the I/O graphs that you can get to from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/sql, clicking on your instance, and then changing the graph to Read/Write Operations.

I do not know of a way to find the Cloud SQL I/Os for a specific statement. [MySQL Profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) can show MySQL's measure of I/Os for a query, but this is measuring a slightly different thing than what Cloud SQL charges for, so might not give you exact results.